# Python: summing elements in a sequence in increasing order and vice versa

Tags: python

I have the following sequence: (4, 6, 5, 11) 
I want to have the outcome: (4, 10, 15, 26)

Can someone help me?

```
q = list()
for i in enumerate(seq):
    q = [x[i] + x[i-1] for x in seq]
```

What if I would like to do the reverse? from (4, 10, 15, 26) to (4, 6, 5, 11)

Comment: Did you try to run your code? If no, why? If yes, why are you not satisfied with it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
i = [4, 6, 5, 11]
j = [sum(i[:k+1]) for k in range(len(i))]
print(j)
```

Answer (score 1):

For Python3, use `itertools.accumulate`:

```
import itertools
s = (4, 6, 5, 11)
final_list = list(itertools.accumulate(s))
```

Output:

```
[4, 10, 15, 26]
```

For Python2, you can use a generator:

```
def accumulate(s):
   val = 0
   for i in s:
      val += i
      yield val

print(list(accumulate((4, 6, 5, 11))))
```

Output:

```
[4, 10, 15, 26]
```

Inverse:

```
def inverse(s):
   first = s[0]
   second = 0
   yield first
   for i in s[1:]:
      yield i-first
      first = i

print(list(inverse([4, 10, 15, 26])))
```

Output:

```
[4, 6, 5, 11]
```

Comment: If you would love to do the inverse of accumulate e.g. from  (4, 10, 15, 26)  to (4, 6, 5, 11) ?

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient but you can do:

```
x= [4, 6, 5, 11]
y = [sum(x[0:i+1] for i in range(len(x))]
```